# How to secure our app

Tags: android, ios, security

How to secure our app data to prevent hacking in app/ API and protect some sensitive data? 
- How to transfer all secure data to other device: for example I have some special setting in my app in device A, I want next time if user login in another device in device B, my app in device B have fully special setting from device A.

Comment: Use `encryption- decryption` mechanism and use `Proguard` too.

Comment: Data backup - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html
Security - https://developer.android.com/training/best-security.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Behind every great mobile app is a great backend, but building a REST API for your app can be a bit daunting if you haven’t done so before. Fear not! I suggest you to find some tutorial about how to build your REST API using Node.js, and connect it to an iOS or Android app!, and handle authentication. Some reasons to use Node JS as backend.

- It’s easy to work with JSON in JavaScript!
- Node.js is lightweight and easy to get started with.
- Node.js gives you fine-grained control over your request and responses.

Answer (score 1):

From IOS app perspective, you need to use Cryptographic algorithms to encrypt the data you are transferring. You can use any of Symmetric and asymmetric algorithms to encrypt the data. But in most cases RSA 256 which is a asymmetric cryptographic algorithm is used. You should also use HTTPS certificates to make sure your data is secure.